# Q-learning convergence with stochastic reward function

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, markov-decision-process

Every proof for convergence of Q-learning I can find assumes that the reward is a function $r(s, a, s')$ i.e. deterministic. However, MDPs are often defined with a stochastic reward, as exemplified in the following Bellman equation:

$$q_{\pi}(s,a) = \sum_{s',r}p(s',r|s,a)( r + \gamma \sum_{a'}\pi(a'|s') q_{\pi}(s',a'))$$

Here the reward is stochastic (part of the MDP dynamics $p$).

1. Does Q-learning converge in this more general case?
2. Is there a proof somewhere?

Comment: Could you link to one of the proofs that you think is using a deterministic function for reward? Typically $r(s,a,s')$ when it appears is **not** the reward function, but the *expected* immediate reward function - which is deterministic even when the reward function is stochastic. However. I won't know if that's the case for the ones you are referring unless I see them

Comment: @NeilSlater take a look at this [PDF](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~mtjspaan/readingGroup/ProofQlearning.pdf)

But, you are right, I looked it up in Csaba Szepesvari's book and there $r(s, a, s')$ is clearly the expected reward as you say! And in the convergence proofs this book references, it is clear that they handle the general stochastic reward case.